# Grails message(), messages.properties args not evaluating

Tags: grails

When I call the grails `message()` function to lookup and evaluate a message key pair, it fails to evaluate the arguments.

In my controller, I call the message function:

```
rejectWithError(message(code: "email.validationFailed", args: [session.job.email]))
```

and in messages.properties I have:

```
email.validationFailed=Some message with {0}! Please login with {0} instead.
```

but when the page is rendered, the args are not replaced:

```
Some message with {0}! Please login with {0} instead.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of Grails are you using?  Is `email` a domain class?

Comment: `email` is a string field on a domain class Job that's persisted in the session. I'm using Grails version 2.2.1.

Comment: That didn't work. Even with a restart.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of the following:

to attach it to the `job` object

```
job.errors.reject('job.email.validationFailed', 
                  [session.job.email] as Object[], 
                  'A default error message')
```

or if you want to attach it to the `email` field in the `job` object

```
job.errors.rejectValue('email',
             'job.email.validationFailed',
             [session.job.email] as Object[], 
             'A default error message')
```

See:

- Grails domain errors docs - http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/errors.html
- Spring validation docs - http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html#reject(java.lang.String)

Comment: I'll give this a try. I'm stumped why it wouldn't work with `message(code: "blah", args: [])` though - are my expectations wrong. FYI I'm using this in a `flash.message` assignment...

Comment: I believe you are correct that `message(code:'some.code', args:[])` should work.  What does your gsp look like?  Are you just displaying this message as is (e.g. `${myMessageFromController}`), or are you attempting to use `<g:message ...>` in the gsp?